# How do I align two components inside a HTML table?

Tags: html, css

I need programVersion and userInfo to be on the same line. How would I do this?

what it currently looks like: 
[image]

I tried adding them inside another table.

```html
<table id="sheet" width="100%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="5" width="30px"></td>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="headerrow">
    <td rowspan="2" id="headerrow" width="300" style="border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 0px;">
      <p:graphicImage url="/images/six_logo.png" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="app-header" style="border-radius: 0px 10px 0px 0px;">
      <ui:insert name="header">
        <strong style="font-size: 30px">#{i18n['application.name']}</strong>
      </ui:insert>

      <ui:insert name="programVersion">
        <p>#{pv['ProgramVersion']}</p>
      </ui:insert>

      <ui:insert name="userInfo">
        <div align="right">
          <h:outputText value="#{loginController.userInfo}" />
        </div>
      </ui:insert>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: IF you are in a table anyway, why not use different cells?

Comment: can you achieve this when not using jsf? of ypu can, you have your answer too, if ypu can't, it is not jsf related

Comment: You have to give the full generated HTML code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the scripting you're using to display data but I think following might work for you.

```css
div:first-child {
  display: inline;
}

.first{
  float: left;
}

.second{
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <div class="first">
    0.20.r5 Version
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    dewrf435dsfs345f65
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much.